# What do two 'greater than' symbols mean

Tags: analysis

I'm working through the basic math course on brilliant.org and I found an answer I don't understand [here](https://brilliant.org/practice/always-sometimes-never-2/?p=6). (The 2nd part of the 4th answer option).

What does this mean?

```
-10 < a < 0
```

Is there an implicit AND after `a` ? And therefore does it mean this?

```
-10 < a AND -10 < 0
```

Comment: It means $-10 < a$ and $a < 0$.

Comment: So there IS an implied `AND` in there. Great thank you!

Comment: Bonus fact: sometimes mathematicians will use two less-than symbols to mean "much smaller than", as in $$\epsilon \ll 1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means that $a$ is between $-10$ and $0$

so $a<0$ and $a>-10$

Answer (score 2):

There is an implied `AND`, but not in the way you put it. It really means
$$-10 < a\quad\text{AND} \quad a<0 $$

In other words, $a$ is between $-10$ and $0$, excluding end points. In general, $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 <... < x_n$ means
$$x_1 < x_2\quad\text{AND} \quad x_2 < x_3 \quad\text{AND} \quad x_3 < x_4 \quad ...\quad x_{n-2} < x_{n-1} \quad\text{AND} \quad x_{n-1} <x_n $$

Comment: Presumably, you mean "but **not** in the way you put it."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, thanks. Must have typed a bit too quickly. Have corrected it.

Comment: What do you mean by `excluding end points` ?

Comment: @AgentZebra I mean that $a$ is between $-10$ and $0$ but *not equal* to either $-10$ or $0$. Conversely, $-10 \leq a \leq 0$ would mean that $a$ is between $-10$ and $0$ *including* end points.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit AND but not the way you think.

$-10 < a < 0$ means
$-10 < a$ AND $a < 0.$

It is a convenient way to express the values a can take given an upper and a lower limit.

$\{x \mid -10 < a < 0\}$ is equivalent to $(-10, 0)$ in interval notation.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand it.